# Why am I getting the message that Security Stack Exchange is only partially encrypted?

Tags: encryption, certificates

I realize that this is an information website but it does concern me a bit that I'm getting the message that this website does not supply ownership information.  Does this mean that my posts can be read while in transit?

Comment: I think we need more to go on. Can you show the message? Can you describe your environment?

Comment: if there is a way to attach a screenshot, I would love to.  Everytime, I click on a question, my url has an exclamation point and it tell me that some elements of the website is not encrypted and then the warning tells me that the website does not supply ownership information.

Answer (score 5):

When you visit `https://security.stackexchange.com/`, in some instances you'll be served content (ads specifically, it appears) that is over `http` rather than `https`. Most modern browsers will warn when this happens as you are seeing.

The risks are that the content that is served over non-TLS connections can be viewed and manipulated before reaching your browser in an otherwise encrypted channel. Further, any cookies that are not marked as secure while content within the same URL is served over both `http` and `https` will be exposed.

Example:

`https://www.example.com/` serves mixed content from `http://cdn.example.com/`. Any cookies scoped to `.example.com` that do not have the secure flag set will be exposed while your browser fetches resources from `http://cdn.example.com/`.

Not only ads, but also within SE itself: `<script src="http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/js?id=a51-ad-container" type="text/javascript"></script>`.

Comment: +1 It's odd that browsers get angry about mixed content and SHA1 certificates, while not complaining at all about pure http sites. This leads my mother to say things like "your HTTPS Everywhere add-on makes the internet less safe!"

Comment: Not really. Browsers don't display a "lock" or whatever signal when using HTTP so there is no need to inform the user that something is different from normal encrypted communication. The browser signals, such as a "partially encrypted message", are about preventing false appearance of security.